How to fit with constraints?
I have a curve defined by sp(r) with r in [0,1], and I would like to fit a degree 6 polynomial pol(r) to this curve under specific constraints. The fitting polynomial must satisfy the following conditions: it should always be non-negative and must also be less than or equal to the original curve, specifically 0 <= pol(r) <= sp(r).
Given the following data points:
data = {{0, sp[0]}, {0.05, sp[0.05]}, {0.10, sp[0.10]}, {0.99, sp[0.99]}, {1, sp[1]}}

I have been using the command:
fit[r_] = Fit[data, {1,r,r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5, r^6}, r]

What changes should I make to my commands in order to ensure that the fitting polynomial meets these constraints?

You have 5 data points and 7 parameters. Therefore a fitted polynomial always goes through the data points.
